# How to get the php address bar, if I use Vue?

Tags: php, vue.js

```
echo $_SERVER ['PHP_SELF'];
```

always returns the index.php
my line looks like this:
mysite.com/Nature-Wallpaper
how do I get "Nature-Wallpaper" or all line "mysite.com/Nature-Wallpaper"?

Comment: In a Vue component? How is PHP related to this if you're using Vue?

Comment: @kerbholz  spa.blade.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

echo `$_SERVER ['REQUEST_UR'];`

**'REQUEST_URI'**
The URI which was given in order to access this page; for instance, `'/index.html'`.

This is what you are looking for `path_info`

```
$_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
```

**'PATH_INFO'**
Contains any client-provided pathname information trailing the actual script filename but preceding the query string, if available. For instance, if the current script was accessed via the URL `http://www.example.com/php/path_info.php/some/stuff?foo=bar, then $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` would contain `/some/stuff`.

More examples : https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Or you can use `.htaccess` 301 redirect all.

Htaccess solution :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain-name.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain-name.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !Nature-Wallpaper/
RewriteRule (.*) /Nature-Wallpaper/$1 [L]
```

Now your site root will be changed to `Nature-Wallpaper`

See more explanition on htaccess here : https://www.siteground.com/kb/how_to_change_my_document_root_folder_using_an_htaccess_file/

Comment: i get laravel error: `Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Undefined index: PATH_INFO (View: /var/www/html/resources/views/spa.blade.php)`

Comment: @algebra changing laravel site root to a folder : https://www.techalyst.com/posts/change-hosting-domain-document-root-for-laravel-project

Comment: See this is well : https://www.dvdheiden.nl/2015/06/laravel-5-quick-tip-change-the-public-directory/

Comment: /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf configured like this: RewriteEngine on
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public
    <Directory "/var/www/html/public">